# th width not working?

Tags: html, css

A little background, I am trying to implement the minimal amount of pieces of this to get fixed report headers from this demo:
http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html

I have it working except none of my headers rows (i havemultiple header rows) line up vertically with the cells below.  I have set the width of all cells to the same with this css:

```
td {
    width: 100px;  
}

th {
    width: 100px;
}
```

And changing the th width does have an impact, but for some reason they are not getting a width of 100 pixels.  From header row to header row the widths are different for some reason.  **How can I force all the cells to the same width?**

Below is the rest of the CSS that is in place.  I am testing with firefox and trying to get the frozen headers to work with as little CSS.  Some of the CSS in the linked example is very specific to that layout, and I am trying to work something out that will work with any editing for varying numbers of columns/rows.  It currently is working with the exception that the cells are not all aligned.

```
#reportPlace table thead tr {
    display: block;
}

#reportPlace table tbody {
    display: block;
    height: 262px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**NOTE: If I remove both `display: block` styles it fixes the issue with the column widths, but then the header rows are no longer frozen.**

Fired it out part way.  I set block display on the entire table, instead of on each th element and and body, and now all the columns line up.  Because each th row in the multiple row header had block set seperately, they were autosizing width independently.  However, the width setting is still ignored and I'm gonna need that to format the report.

```
#reportPlace table /*thead tr*/ {
    display: block;
}

#reportPlace table tbody {
/*    display: block;*/
    height: 262px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Sample HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Untitled Page</title>
  <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="reportPlace">
    <table border="0">
      <thead>
        <tr class="fixedHeader">
          <th class="titleAllLockedCell">
            <span>&nbsp;</span>
          </th>
          <th class="titleTopLockedCell">
            <span>Fruits</span>
          </th>
          <th class="titleTopLockedCell">
            <span>Vegitables</span>
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="fixedHeader">
          <th class="titleAllLockedCell">
            <span>&nbsp;</span>
          </th>
          <th class="titleTopLockedCell">
            <span>Original</span>
          </th>
          <th class="titleTopLockedCell">
            <span>Original</span>
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="fixedHeader">
          <th class="titleAllLockedCell">
            <span>&nbsp;</span>
          </th>
          <th class="titleTopLockedCell">
            <span>2009</span>
          </th>
          <th class="titleTopLockedCell">
            <span>2009</span>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="titleLeftLockedCell">
            <span>1-02</span>
          </td>
          <td class="valueCell">
            <span>65412&nbsp;</span>
          </td>
          <td class="valueCell">
            <span>16542&nbsp;</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="titleLeftLockedCell">
            <span>1-03</span>
          </td>
          <td class="valueCell">
            <span>456052&nbsp;</span>
          </td>
          <td class="valueCell">
            <span>1654652&nbsp;</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="titleLeftLockedCell">
            <span>1-04</span>
          </td>
          <td class="valueCell">
            <span>564654&nbsp;</span>
          </td>
          <td class="valueCell">
            <span>654654&nbsp;</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is a typo in your css, though I doubt it is causing this issue since the rule will be ignored. `td{ width: 100; }` should be `td{ width: 100px; }`

Comment: @Kevin I don't that's an error at all since the final semicolon is usually omitted by JS optimizers for optimization.

Comment: @Gio, we're talking css here. Very few properties can be unitless and it is suggested that none should be. Thus, the `px` is required on the definition.

Comment: Ah yes you are right, I had made that mistake while playing around and then fixed but it still doesn't work.

Comment: how about posting the html to help visualise your problem?

Comment: @Kevin ah, I missed the units added there.

Comment: K, I will get some html (sort of generating it dynamically).  See my note, it is the `display:block` settings that are causing the issue, but if I remove them then header rows are no longer fixed.

Comment: @Aaron, `display` other than `table-cell` on `th` and `td` elements are not well supported in browsers. Can you expand on what you are trying to accomplish and not the problem at hand? This might get you an answer.

Comment: @Kevin I am trying to get the header rows to stay frozen at the top of the page whenever the data is scrolled up and down, such as in the linked example.

Comment: Ironically the demo you're trying to mimick also has the headers out of alignment with the rest of the cells (at leasr as I see it).

Comment: There are some browsers/versions it doesn't work with.  His page looks fine in my browser but my page does not in the same browser.

Comment: @Aaron, manipulating tables at all (besides basic styles) is still not supported well enough to do what you want. I would try hiding the `th` (for accessibility) and go with other stylable elements for the "fixed" heading.

Comment: @Kevin When you say I can not do that, I don;t understand because I linked a page that shows a working example(at least in firefox 3.6).  I am simply trying to weed out of that CSS the parts that are needed for the fixed header and aligned widths.  Because I am generating the html programmatically I have certain challenges when setting styles/classes from code, so I was just trying to simplify the CSS.  I used firebug to comment out all of his CSS except for the above and it worked fine on his page.  So there is some nuance still in my way that I don't understand.

Comment: @Aaron, **not supported well enough** is the key phrase here. If you want to support one browser you do that. You will not find enough support to accomplish your goals across browsers.

Comment: In his example he selects each column seperately with `html>body tbody.scrollContent td + td`, but I need to be able to set a width for all cells because of the dynamic nature of my report.  I don't mind if they are all the same width, but I need to be able to control the width, and for some reason the `display:block` causes the width to be ignored.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks, but I think you misunderstood my goal.  I already stated previously that I understand it doesn't work on all browsers, and that is explained on the linked page as well.  I'm not trying to accomplish cross browser compatibility.  I don't care as long as it works on mine.  It is an internally facing app and all my users care are having the headers frozen, and they could care less about whether or not my app works under Opera or an ancient version of IE.  My goal is just to get it looking right in my browser and understand why display:block causes the width to be ignored.

Comment: Are you aiming for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/wnCAC/1/

Comment: I'm aiming for this: http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html

Comment: In my case I had to add `th { display: inline-block; box-sizing: border-box; width: 300px; }` for mine to work and obey my widths even with colspan elements

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I needed to use the `min-width:100px` style instead of the `width` style.

Other issues I've found since include requiring CSS `table { table-layout: fixed; width:100%; }` as tables require a width be set for the columns to respect width.

Having a first row which contains any `colspan` can also be an issue, so I include an additional row as the first row which has no border and 0 height(essentially invisible) and has individual cells(no colspans) so that widths can be established by that first "fake" row, and then the second row with colspan's doesn't cause an issue.  Note that you shouldn't 0 out the padding/margin as you'd want that first row to have the same as other rows so that widths are properly established:

```
<tr class='scaffolding'>...</tr>

tr.scaffolding, .scaffolding td {
    border:none;
    padding-top:0;
    padding-bottom:0;
    height:0;
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: If you add to this wiki please separate any other potential issues/troubleshooting steps with their own headers.

Comment: If anyone's using bootstrap and came to this question, probably you just need to add `table-responsive` to the table's classes.

Comment: highlight `table { table-layout: fixed; }` is important

Comment: @zed You are a legend, saved me a **** ton of time!